# JQuery Ajax call is doing nothing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

So, I have a list of users that I am using PHP to produce into HTML. I include a button on every row to disable the user's access to the application, I want to use JQuery to call an AJAX object to update the database onto a field called "usrStatus", but whenever I click on the button, the alert "Successfully Called" does appear, but nothing happens on the database.

What am I missing?

### HTML Button to call AJAX.

```
<button id="block-1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger ublock" name="blockUser" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Block User">
    <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

### JQuery Function

```
$('.ublock').click(function() {
    var $userId = $(this).attr('id').slice(9);
    if ($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-lock')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-success').toggleClass('btn-danger');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-lock').toggleClass('fa-unlock-alt');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Websites/Mahle/Resources/PHP/Usuarios/bloquearUsuario.php',
            data: {idUsuario: $userId, status: "Bloqueado"},
            success: function(result) {
                alert('Successfully called!!');
            },
            error: function(exception) {
                alert('Exception:'+exception);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

### PHP Code "bloquearUsuario.php"

```
include('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Websites/Mahle/Resources/PHP/loginDatabase.php');

$qry = "UPDATE MahlePruebas.Usuarios SET usrStatus = ? WHERE idUsuarios = ?";

$usrUpdate = $dbLogin->prepare($qry) or die('Error preparando query (bloquear usuario): ' . $dbLogin->error . " (".$dbLogin->errno.")" . "\n");
$usrUpdate->bind_param("ss",
  $_POST['idUsuario'],
  $_POST['status']
) or die('Error preparando query (bloquear usuario): ' . $dbLogin->error . " (".$dbLogin->errno.")" . "\n");
$usrUpdate->execute() or die('Error preparando query (bloquear usuario): ' . $dbLogin->error . " (".$dbLogin->errno.")" . "\n");
```

Comment: it may be successfully called, but what is in `result`

Comment: `$userId = $(this).attr('id').slice(9);` - so the first 9 characters of the `id` are not part of the userid, correct?

Comment: Correct, the first 9 elements are just used to identify the element, the rest is the ID for the record.
I am barely starting with AJAX calls, so I am not sure how to properly fetch the result..

Comment: `console.log(result)` in your success callback

Comment: Console log is not showing nothing, just a blank line and at the right a reference to the file and line that called the log entry.

Comment: yeah, just realised your php does not return anything, that's not the problem, but `UPDATE MahlePruebas.Usuarios SET usrStatus = ? WHERE idUsuarios = ?` wont fail if you give a non-existent `idUsuarios` - which is why I asked about the format of the `id` ... try `console.log($userId)` before the ajax call to see if the ID is correct

Comment: Ok, log for XMLHTTPRequests was not enabled, it shwed the following:

`XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8888/Websites/Mahle/Resources/PHP/Usuarios/bloquearUsuario.php".`

Comment: look at the **POST** parameters for that request to be sure that the userId is correct

Comment: Just confirmed with `console.log($userId)` and it shows the correct ID.

Comment: you need to print both $_POST values 

echo  $_POST['idUsuario'] . $_POST['status'] and check , result with console log status

Comment: Just did, the $_POST, console log is reporting proper values. Does this mean the problem is with the query? If I run it directly from my terminal, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
$qry = "UPDATE MahlePruebas.Usuarios SET usrStatus = ? WHERE idUsuarios = ?";
```

first ? is for status, second ? is for idUsuarios

in `bind_param` ... you have `idUsuario` then `status` ... so, I believe these need to be reversed

so instead of

```
$usrUpdate->bind_param("ss",
  $_POST['idUsuario'],
  $_POST['status']
)
```

use

```
$usrUpdate->bind_param("ss",
  $_POST['status'],
  $_POST['idUsuario']
)
```

Comment: I don't believe this ... I've been staring at this issue for a solid hour! thanks for that..

Comment: took me 15 minutes to realise it too :p